# django filter model with many-to-many fields

Tags: python, django

My model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
```

Here Book subjects is in many-to-many relationship with Subject model.

How can i get all the books having the same related subjects.
For example all the books having the subjects id [2,3,6]

Comment: This is a guess, but does `Book.objects.filter(subjects__in = [2, 3, 6])` work?

Comment: This shows all the books having subjects id 2 OR books having subjects id  3 OR books having subjects id  6

Comment: Then something like `Book.objects.filter(subjects__id = 2).filter(subjects__id = 3).filter(subjects__id = 6)`? You'd have to add these on in a for loop.

Comment: wow.. it is working. I couldnot think that. Thank you fletom

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the `Q` objects wont work.

Some initial data:

```
>>> from subjects.models import Subject, Book
>>> s1 = Subject.objects.create(name='subject_1', description='description 1')
>>> s2 = Subject.objects.create(name='subject_2', description='description 2')
>>> s3 = Subject.objects.create(name='subject_3', description='description 3')
>>> s4 = Subject.objects.create(name='subject_4', description='description 4')
>>> b1 = Book.objects.create(title='one_subject_book', subtitle='one subject')
>>> b1.subjects = [s1]
>>> b2 = Book.objects.create(title='three_subject_book', subtitle='three subjects')
>>> b2.subjects = [s2,s3,s4]
>>> b3 = Book.objects.create(title='four_subject_book', subtitle='four subjects')
>>> b3.subjects = [s1,s2,s3,s4]
```

Lets first check the naive approach with `subjects__in=[s1,s2,s3]`. We are looking for only one book as a result since only `b3` contains all subjects.

```
>>> Book.objects.filter(subjects__in=[s1,s2,s3])
DEBUG (0.001) 
    SELECT `subjects_book`.`id`, `subjects_book`.`title`, `subjects_book`.`subtitle` 
    FROM `subjects_book` 
    INNER JOIN `subjects_book_subjects` ON ( `subjects_book`.`id` = `subjects_book_subjects`.`book_id` ) 
    WHERE `subjects_book_subjects`.`subject_id` IN (1, 2, 3) 
    LIMIT 21; args=(1, 2, 3)
[<Book: Book object>, <Book: Book object>, <Book: Book object>, <Book: Book object>, <Book: Book object>, <Book: Book object>]
```

We are simply searching for `books` containing `s1` OR `s2` OR `s3`. That's why we get such a result. We have duplicate results because we didn't used `.distinct()`

Now lets try with the `Q` objects.

Just want to mention that:

```
Book.objects.filter(Q(subjects=s1)&Q(subjects=s2)&Q(subjects=s3))
```

is the same as:

```
Book.objects.filter(reduce(lambda q1,q2: q1&q2, [Q(subjects=s) for s in [s1,s2,s3]]))
```

Just a more dynamic version where u can easily just change the list with the `subjects`.

```
>>> Book.objects.filter(reduce(lambda q1,q2: q1&q2, [Q(subjects=s) for s in [s1,s2,s3]]))
DEBUG (0.260) 
    SELECT `subjects_book`.`id`, `subjects_book`.`title`, `subjects_book`.`subtitle` 
    FROM `subjects_book` 
    INNER JOIN `subjects_book_subjects` ON ( `subjects_book`.`id` = `subjects_book_subjects`.`book_id` ) 
    WHERE (
        `subjects_book_subjects`.`subject_id` = 1 
        AND `subjects_book_subjects`.`subject_id` = 2 
        AND `subjects_book_subjects`.`subject_id` = 3
    ) LIMIT 21; args=(1, 2, 3)
[]
```

We got and empty result set. This would be normal if you inspect the query. We can't have a row containing three different values of `subject_id` at the same time.
The reason we get such a query is because we apply all the `Q`filters at once in a singe `.filter` statement. Read more about that at [Spanning multi-valued relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships).

In order to achieve the correct result from `MySQL` point of view, we have to JOIN the `subjects_book_subjects` table for every `subject` we want to filter on. In the `ORM` perspective this can be achieved by series of consecutive `.filter` statements:

```
Book.objects.filter(subjects=s1).filter(subjects=s2).filter(subjects=s3)
```

In a more fashion way this look this:

```
books_queryset = reduce(lambda books,s: books.filter(subjects=s),[s1,s2,s3], Book.objects.all())
```

as example:

```
>>> reduce(lambda books,s: books.filter(subjects=s),[s1,s2,s3], Book.objects.all())
DEBUG (0.001) 
    SELECT `subjects_book`.`id`, `subjects_book`.`title`, `subjects_book`.`subtitle` 
    FROM `subjects_book` 
    INNER JOIN `subjects_book_subjects` ON ( `subjects_book`.`id` = `subjects_book_subjects`.`book_id` ) 
    INNER JOIN `subjects_book_subjects` T4 ON ( `subjects_book`.`id` = T4.`book_id` ) 
    INNER JOIN `subjects_book_subjects` T6 ON ( `subjects_book`.`id` = T6.`book_id` ) 
    WHERE (
        `subjects_book_subjects`.`subject_id` = 1 
        AND T4.`subject_id` = 2 
        AND T6.`subject_id` = 3
    ) LIMIT 21; args=(1, 2, 3)
[<Book: Book object>]
```