# Select record from a list of ids through M2M relations

Tags: django, orm, m2m

First, sorry for my bad english, this problem is not trivial to explain so I hope you will understand me.

I have 2 models as the following:

```
class A(models.Model):
   code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
   list_of_b = models.ManyToManyField('B')


class B(models.Model):
   code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
```

I aim to retrieve instances of A which match exactly with a given list of B ids.

For example, imagine I have the following records of A in my database:

```
id: 1 - code: X - list_of_b: [1, 2, 4, 6]
id: 2 - code: Y - list_of_b: [2, 5, 6]
id: 3 - code: Z - list_of_b: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

With `[2, 5, 6]` as given list, I should retrieve the record 2 and 3, not 1.

I succeed to retrieve records with an exact match of ids with this query:

```
queryset = A.objects.prefetch_related('list_of_b')
queryset = queryset.annotate(nb=Count('list_of_b')).filter(nb=len(my_list))
for id in my_list:
    queryset = queryset.filter(list_of_b=id)
```

It works for the record 2 but not for the record 3.

Thanks for any help. Don't hesitate to question me if not clear enough. ;)

**EDIT:**

Just one more thing: it's also possible that `my_list` contains more IDs than necessary. For exemple, with `[2, 5, 6, 7]` I should retrieve records 2 and 3.

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359755/django-filter-model-with-many-to-many-fields/28375377#28375377).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's what I've done in my solution for exact match, but the point here is to select exact match record __and more__, take a look at my example for further details.

Comment: Oh, yes I didn't notice. However @catavaran is right, you are not getting record 3 because of `filter(nb=len(my_list))`

Comment: Adding a new rule in my example, just removing filter on element count doesn't work for it. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hmm, the "new rule" is little confusing, then why we do not expect record one to be returned? Can you write what you need in a plain SQL?

Comment: Hmm... You're right, So, I don't know how to do the trick then. I need time to think about what I exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the filter by count:

```
queryset = A.objects.prefetch_related('list_of_b')
for id in my_list:
    queryset = queryset.filter(list_of_b=id)
```